# Creating a prepare-bind insert statement with a TIMESTAMP datatype

Tags: java, sql, yugabytedb

I am trying to insert some rows using a prepare-bind statement. One of the columns is of type `TIMESTAMP`. How do I bind the variable for this column with the current epoch time?

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders {
  user_id TEXT,
  order_time TIMESTAMP,
  order_id UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  order_details TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, order_time DESC, order_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES %s (user_id)
);
```

I have the following prepare statement code:

```
String stmt = "INSERT INTO orders " +
              "(user_id, order_time, order_details) " + 
              "VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
PreparedStatement p = connection.prepareStatement(stmt);
```

Now I am trying to bind the current epoch time `System.currentTimeMillis()` to variable 2 in this statement. How should I do that?

Comment: can you clarify the last sentence please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding Java type to your SQL's `TIMESTAMP` is most likely `java.sql.Timestamp`.  You can generate a current timestamp using:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

So, your prepared statement code might look like:

```
String stmt = "INSERT INTO orders " +
              "(user_id, order_time, order_details) " + 
              "VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
PreparedStatement p = connection.prepareStatement(stmt);
p.setString(1, "Karthik");
p.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
p.setString(3, "here is some order text");
```

Comment: The OP said `to variable 3 in this` this make the question unclear, nice answer as well :)

Comment: @YCF_L You didn't need to delete your answer, I was only pointing this out to you :-)

Comment: Its ok, the question was not clear, I will wait the OP to clarify it, but your answer is more reasonable

Comment: My bad. I did mean variable 2, have updated my question. This does solve my issue, thanks folks!